# how to analyse crash report

Tags: swift, crash-reports

i need to collect crash reports, but i don't understand them.
For testing purposes i make the app crash with just these 2 lines in a viewDidLoad():

```
var test:String?
test!.isEmpty
```

now, while debugging the console gives me a helpful output:

```
2022-04-29 11:31:34.837188+0200 My App[9270:4377453] My_App/WelcomeViewController.swift:26: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

i also find a new ips-file in my devices analytics sections of the settings, but i don't see a similar error message anywhere in that file. How can i find out why the app crashed from that file?

Answer (score 0):

Lets split the error message into parts:

> 2022-04-29 11:31:34.837188+0200

This is the timestamp. When the crash occurred

> My_App/WelcomeViewController.swift:26

This is location of the crash in source code. `WelcomeViewController.swift` file, line `26`

> found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Why the crash occurred. Looks like there is an [optional data type](https://www.programiz.com/swift-programming/optionals#:%7E:text=However%20there%20is%20another%20data,optional%20as%20a%20shoe%20box.) in your code which you tried to force unwrap (maybe using `!`). This would have worked if the value of the variable was not `nil` but it crashed because it was.

Hope this helps. If you need more info please post source code around the file and line mentioned above.

Comment: i understand the error message. What i don't understand is, how i would get this from the ips file, when i didn't have the device plugged in